# Shorten link from Google Docs using tinyurl

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, url-shortener

I've seen this method over the internet: [Create Short URLs Using APIs and Google Docs](http://www.lebseodesign.com/2011/04/create-short-urls-using-apis-and-google-docs/#ixzz2m6EOxQ7v)

How can I use this method using www.tinyurl.com?

Can you please help me? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No credentials are required to access the tinyurl api. It is dead simple, requiring only the long url in the query:

```
http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=<longUrl>
```

A spreadsheet function similar to those in the referenced article would be:

```
= importData(concatenate("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=",B1))
```

Reference: [Tinyurl has an API](http://scripting.com/stories/2007/06/27/tinyurlHasAnApi.html).

Answer (score 0):

=importData is only for googlesheets.
Which answers this question.

But for those who use Excel you can use VBA code

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub tinyURL()
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Copy As Integer
    Dim Paste As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim URL As String

    i = 2
    Copy = 2
    Paste = 2

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    'loops until column A is empty
    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))

     'Copy from list in Column A and paste result into column B
     URL = "INSERT THE TINYURL API URL HERE ENDING WITH =" & Range("A" & Copy)
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=ws.Range("B" & Paste))

    With qt
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .FieldNames = True
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebTables = 1
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    i = i + 1
    Copy = Copy + 1
    Paste = Paste + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```